# how to fix race condition in golang?

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine

i am trying to fix race condition in golang, i have used waitgroup as you can see i have added two waitgroup and calling Done() as well. But still the output is not exptected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var counter int = 0

func task(m string, n int,  wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ {
        counter = n
        time.Sleep(100000)
        fmt.Println(m, counter)
        counter = 0
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go task("first", 1, &wg) // i want "first" task should get always 1
    wg.Add(1)
    go task("second", 2, &wg) // // i want "second" task should get always 2
    wg.Wait()
}
```

above program output

```
second 1
first 1
first 1
second 1
first 2
second 2
second 2
...
```

expected output

```
second 2
first 1
first 1
second 2
first 1
second 2
second 2
...
```

Comment: A wait group is used to wait for goroutines, it doesn't magically synchronize data access. When accessing the same variable from multiple goroutines, you need synchronization. The easiest is a mutex. But in your example, this will only work if you also hold the mutex during the sleep call.

Answer (score -3):

to anyone who is looking for how to use sync.Mutex for synchronization in golang. this could help. Please comment or reply if this solution is not correct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var counter int = 0

func task(m string, n int,  wg *sync.WaitGroup, mux *sync.Mutex) {
    
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ {
        mux.Lock()
        //your shared resource
        counter = n
        time.Sleep(100000)
        fmt.Println(m, counter)
        counter = 0
        //end of your shared resource
        mux.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mux sync.Mutex
    wg.Add(1)
    go task("first", 1, &wg, &mux)
    wg.Add(1)
    go task("second", 2, &wg, &mux)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: This it's the correct usage, but it's pointless: you're now serializing the execution of your two goroutines. Why even have them as goroutines?

Comment: @Marc i thought this is the solution if two go routine try to access same resource without race condition.

Comment: Sure, there won't be a race condition, but that's because your second goroutine is just waiting until the first one is finished. I recommend you take the tour of go, it covers some useful synchronization features.

Comment: There is no reason for the shared variable at all here, since you can get the exact same output printing `n`. The only thing you have done is make the order of `first` and `second` non-deterministic. If that's what you want, then great, but you only need the mutex for that.

Comment: @JimB the reason is i wanted to learn how synchronization works in golang. thanks,  mutex is the answer here as Marc pointed that too.